# How to avoid double-encoding of [] when using Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, url, urlencode, query-string

I've a Spring Boot 2.2.5 application calling this REST endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/usable/search")
public List<Provider> findUsable(
      @RequestParam(name = "country-id", required = false) Integer countryId,
      @RequestParam(name = "network-ids[]", required = false) List<Integer> networkIds,
      @RequestParam(name = "usages[]") Set<Usage> usages)
```

My caller does

```
val url = clientUri.toString() + configuration.getUrl().getUseableProvidersForNetworks(); % 'providers/usable/search?'
val builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
      .queryParam("usages[]", USAGES)
      .queryParam("network-ids[]", networkIds);
val response =
      restTemplate.exchange(
          builder.toUriString(),
          HttpMethod.GET,
          entity,
          new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Provider>>() {});
```

where `USAGES` is a `Set<Usage>` and `networkIds` is a `List<Integer>`.

The RestTemplate is created by

```
RestTemplate eurekaRestTemplate() {
    val requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    return new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory));
  }
```

Problem: The `[]` get double encoded to `%255B%255D` and I end up with a call to

`providers/usable/search?usages%255B%255D=MESSAGE_DELIVERY&network-ids%255B%255D=2145118475&network-ids%255B%255D=-1536358371`

Which obviously doesn't work; the server misses e.g. `usages[]`. It works with curl with `[]` instead of `%255B%255D`.

How can I avoid that?

I'm aware of [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8888) and [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#web-uri-encoding), but that didn't help yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to call `UriComponentsBuilder.build(false)` to instruct the `UriComponentsBuilder` *not* to encode the url:

```
val response = restTemplate.exchange(
              builder.build(false).toUriString(),
              HttpMethod.GET,
              entity,
              new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Provider>>() {});
```

This is tricky because a test with Mockito/JUnit of this will tell you that the url is *not* encoded while a test with `MockRestServiceServer` will show one level of encoding (`[]` become `%5B%5D`).

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to pass the encoded url directly to `RestTemplate`, you can instruct `RestTemplate` to not encode the url by passing the `java.net.URI` instead of a String.
Here's an example using `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents`

```
String url = "https://someurl/this%2Fis%2Fencoded/";
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).build(true);
ResponseEntity<String[]> file = template.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), 
HttpMethod.GET, entity,String[].class);
```

By passing `UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).build(true)` You are essentially letting `UriComponents` know that your url is already encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't be dealing with using []. I mean, it's not necessary to name your parameters using "[]". 
Why would you do that?

```
val builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
      .queryParam("usages", USAGES)
      .queryParam("network-ids", networkIds);
```

will perfectly work for:

```
public List<Provider> findUsable(
      @RequestParam(name = "country-id", required = false) Integer countryId,
      @RequestParam(name = "network-ids", required = false) List<Integer> networkIds,
      @RequestParam(name = "usages") Set<Usage> usages)
```

Hope it helps!

Hint: be careful when using array/collection parameters on URLs, there's a URL length limit that you must consider

Comment: Thanks, but the API **is as it is**. *I* would use `@RequestBody` .